# Why is silver(I) phosphate so unexpectedly thermally stable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, stability, solid-state-chemistry

> Silver(I) oxide is completely decomposed in air already at $\pu{300 °C}.$
> Formulate the decomposition reaction and the corresponding mass action expression.
> $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ can be melted at $\pu{800°C}$ without decomposition.
> Explain the unexpected thermal stability.

The decomposition reaction and the corresponding mass action from the first part are:

$$\ce{Ag2O(s) <=> 2 Ag(s) + 1/2 O2(g)} \qquad K'_p = \sqrt{p(\ce{O2})}$$

But how can the thermal stability of $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ be justified?

Comment: Hint: oxygen combines to form O2. What about PO4?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Polyphosphate structures?

Comment: Is PO4 found by itself?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is it something like P4O10?

Comment: PO4 ≠ P4O10. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't know what you mean with your first comment. "oxygen combines to form O2. What about PO4?" Didn't you asked to what PO4 combines?

Comment: Consider entropy changes in the reactions, the total energy balance.

Comment: Fun fact: Although silver(I) phosphate is thermally stable, it is very photosensitive and can photolytically decompose: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=66463

Comment: @ Spinell. $\ce{PO4}$ does not exist. It is not a stuff. It is an ion. If silver phosphate decomposes, it may produce metallic silver $\ce{Ag}$. Why not ? But it cannot produce $\ce{PO4}$, as neutral $\ce{PO4}$ does not exist, even by dimerizing or being transformed into some new molecule. This is the main difference between the pyrolysis of $\ce{Ag2O}$ and the pyrolysis of $\ce{Ag3PO4}$. $\ce{Ag2O}$ may produce $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{O2}$. But $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ cannot produce anything with $\ce{PO4}$. This is why it resists pyrolysis.

Comment: @Maurice "..even by dimerizing or being transformed into some new molecul." But what happens at idk. 4000°C (or whatever temperature is finnaly enough for pyrolysis of Ag3PO4)? What would the decomposition products look like? I mean, some temperature must always be sufficient for pyrolysis.

Comment: I don't know what happens to $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ at  very high temperatures (> $2000$°C). But I think that this salt is decomposed  into oxides then into elements, by a reaction like : $$\ce{2 Ag3PO4 -> 3 Ag2O + P2O5}$$ which is immediately followed by $$\ce{2 Ag2O -> 4 Ag + O2}$$ and $\ce{O2}$ is partially decomposed into $2$ oxygen atoms. And maybe a fraction of $\ce{P2O5}$ is decomposed into elementary phosphorous and oxygen.

Comment: Since silver oxide decomposes at 300C it will not be an intermediate compound at 2000C. A more likely scenerio would be transfer of electrons from phosphate oxygens to silver giving P2O3:  2Ag3PO4  =  6Ag + 2PO4[!]; [2PO4 = P2O8 = p2O3 +5/2O2] The equation is!!  2Ag3PO4  =  6Ag  + P2O3 + 5/2O2. This balances for mass and redox. It is possible to write equations that balance for mass and not for redox.

Comment: Compare it with silver sulfate with similar behavior. (m.p. 652.2–660 °C, b.p(decomp)  1,085 °C)

Answer (score 0):

Silver orthophosphate just like other orthophosphates are thermally stable because they a) they have a strong ionic bond b)evolution of phosphorus pentoxide requires huge energy [See: [Do (some or all) phosphates thermally decompose?]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172650/do-some-or-all-phosphates-thermally-decompose)

It has been noted in the past how stable silver(I) phosphate is and even after prolonged heating, it refuses to convert into a different species and only converting to pyrophosphate at [white heat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20heat) kept for long time:

> Pyrophosphate of silver fuses with extreme facility, even at a temperature below that of redness, yielding a dark brown colored liquid, which, without suffering the least appreciable decomposition, becomes a radiated crystalline mass on cooling. By the first impression of heat, long before fusion, it changes to brownish yellow, and retains when cold a shade of the same color. **Phosphate of silver, on the contrary, is very infusible; so that it may be heated in a glass tube, or on a platinum foil, to full redness, without being fused. Its color changes to a reddish-brown by very slight elevation of temperature but, as it cools, the original yellow tint is restored. At a white heat it is fused; and then, like the pyrophosphate, it assumes a dark brown color, but regains the yellow on cooling. If kept for a long any time in a fused state, a portion of pyrophosphate is generated; and consequently, the mass becomes more fusible, and acquires a paler tint.** A very minute quantity of pyrophosphate greatly increase the fusibility of the phosphate of silver.

**Source**: *The Edinburgh Journal of Science*, Volume 3 by Thomas Clark, **1830**

Comment: Phosphate to pyrophosphate is a condensation reaction involving loss of water. You are proposing an oxidative mechanism involving Ag+.  How about giving an appropriate balanced equation.

Comment: The nonexistant ionic bond has little to do with it. To decompose silver phosphate silver must be reduced an something must be oxidized. Since phosphate cannot be oxidized an O from the phosphate is the only candidate. If it is balanced out there are not enough electrons to go around so phosphate must also oxidize some O, this is not energetically favorable so phosphates are stable beyond expectations whatever they might be. A simpler way to say this is that the P-O bonds in phosphate are very strong.

Answer (score -2):

The stability of oxides and phosphates in general should be compared. I have always wondered about the stability of the O= ion because it is endothermic and many oxides are colored indicating loose electrons somewhere. Stable oxides have high lattice energies as in Al2O3 or MgO or strong covalent bonds as in PO4[3-] or SO4= or even CO2. The comparison is between the oxide ion and the phosphate ion. Also the charge transfer or covalency between the silver ion [or other +ion] should be considered.

Why is the stability of a phosphate "unexpected" phosphates are usually stable compounds. The question is biased and misleading.

I am adding a comment I posted above giving a fictionalized mechanism for phosphate decomposition the actual mechanism is complicated but pondering or researching it might give an idea why phosphates are stable.

Since silver oxide decomposes at 300C it will not be an intermediate compound at 2000C. A more likely scenario would be transfer of electrons from phosphate oxygens to silver giving P2O3:  2Ag3PO4  =  6Ag + 2PO4[!]; [2PO4 = P2O8 = p2O3 +5/2O2] The equation is!!  2Ag3PO4  =  6Ag  + P2O3 + 5/2O2. This balances for mass and redox. It is possible to write equations that balance for mass and not for redox.

Comment: Thank you for your answere but I wasn't really able to extract a fitting answere. Should I argument with ionic character? Your last part doesn't really offer an explanation (at least for me), it seems more like a characterisation but in an exam I couldnt write it like that.

Comment: Phosphates are stable because the P-O bonds are strong.  Metallic oxides with lower lattice energies are more unstable because the O-2 ion is endothermic.

Comment: Isn't the bond between the silver and the phosphate/ oxygen more relevant in the pyrolysis?

Comment: With 2 down votes my answer is questionable. Researching P2O3 it disproportionates to P4O10 and P. Ionic compounds do not have specific metal ion bonds. If anything an Ag-O attraction should aid phosphate decomposition. This subject seems to be inadequately researched.  My opinion is still that phosphate is just a very stable ion.

Comment: After reading the above references They are low T studies not decomposition of phosphates and not relevant.  The MP is a function of the lattice energy. decomposition the stabilityof the anion. The colors observed possibly support my fictionalized mechanism Sine any P formed in an O2 or air atmosphere would be oxidized to phosphate