Thermostability of Metal Carbonates and Nitrates
While studying in high school, I came across the following thermal decomposition reactions:
$$\ce{Li2CO3 -> Li2O + CO2 }$$
$$\ce{MgCO3 -> MgO + CO2}$$
$$\ce{PbCO3 -> PbO + CO2}$$
$$\ce{Ag2CO3 -> 2 Ag + CO2 + ½ O2}$$
$$\ce{HgCO3 -> Hg + CO2 + ½ O2}$$
Basically, some metal carbonates decompose into their metal forms, while others decompose into their oxides.
Furthermore, alkali metal carbonates don't decompose at all, with the exception of Lithium.
I noticed a similar pattern in metal nitrates as well, where $\ce{AgNO3}$ decomposes into $\ce{Ag}$, but $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ decomposes into $\ce{PbO}$.
I want to know why is this so, and what other metals fit in such categories.
I tried looking it up in certain literature, but couldn't find any information other than the periodic trends of thermostability. One classmate suggested the Hard acid and base concept, but that too left me unsatisfied for an answer.

Check for anion polarization by cations and for oxide stability.

@Poutnik Thank you! Turns out, Ag2O and HgO are quite thermally unstable.

..so no reason to form them.  // Check figure 8.2.7 - Periodic table for ionic radii chem.libretexts.org - Atomic_and_Ionic_Radius. It will help you to decide the anion polarization effects, leading to their destabilization.

Alkali and alkaline oxides are quite stable and they require very high heat (almost red hot temperature) to get to elemental state. That's the reason, their carbonates decompose to the oxide. Check: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80460/17368, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28176/17368

For nitrate, check https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150424/do-all-metal-nitrates-give-nitrogen-dioxide-on-decomposition (and links therein). For phosphate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172650/do-some-or-all-phosphates-thermally-decompose
